# Visual Studio 2008 Stops Responding When Attempting to Extract Method

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

Every time I attempt to extract a method in Visual Studio 2008, the IDE stops responding and eventually crashes.  I do not get an error message upon crashing but, the error in the event log is below.  Anyone else ever have this issue?  I have refactored and extracted methods before without issues.  Nothing has been installed recently on my system.  I have also tried restarting Visual Studio and rebooting my machine without success.

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source devenv cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

The data source '{130bada6-e128-423c-9d07-02e4734d45d4}' specifies no supporting providers or a set that are not registered.

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

Comment: Try to repair you visual studio using your its installer....

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that tonight and will update the post with any progress.  It's always something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trying everything under the sun including a repair installation of VS 2008, it ended up being a break point in the code that I was attempting to refactor to a method.  Once, I removed the break point the code refactored (i.e. extracted to a method) without issues.